# C2DM with ClientLogin on the server

Tags: android, push-notification, android-c2dm

I'm working on a server side solution for a mobile application written in Ruby.  Part of our requirements is to notify our distributed clients to phone home to receive updated payload which [Google's C2DM](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/index.html) service seems ideal for.

I've already prototyped and tested everything we need and verified that the solution will work from my local machine.  (Using the [C2DM library for Ruby](https://github.com/cfeduke/c2dm), the link is to my own fork in progress to solve an SSL certificate problem where the cert doesn't cover Google's `api` subdomain.)  Except for one major hiccup in [Google's ClientLogin](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps.html) API:

When deploying to our development application servers I was unable to transmit messages.  Digging deeper into the results I found out that we were receiving a reply from Google that said `CAPTCHAREQUIRED` and a captcha token plus a URL to a captcha image despite the fact I was using a valid `auth_token` I created locally during development.  So I used my own browser to request the CAPTCHA and solve it, then used curl to post the reply from our development server to ClientLogin after which I was able to get the `auth_token` necessary to transmit messages.

This had me worried that when deploying to a production environment a similar authentication challenge will occur.  So a teammate and I performed some more research and found out that while no one knows the exact specifications as to when an `auth_token` may expire there is at least one purported Google engineer who claimed they are valid for "at least two weeks."  Then a suggested solution is that when the ClientLogin response indicates `CAPTCHAREQUIRED` that you page/email an ops/devops person to solve the CAPTCHA and use a page/tool in your server application to submit the answer to get a new `auth_token`.  (If this is what I have to do, I guess Amazon's Mechanical Turk saves the day?)

There is, of course, the real possibility that this information is outdated but that doesn't change the fact that I still need to solve CAPTCHAs at least during initial installation.  We control the production environment so this isn't a very big deal, just a minor inconvenience since we don't know what, exactly, causes a `CAPTCHAREQUIRED` challenge response.  (We theorize that its a previously unknown IP address for the account.)

I can't help but thinking I'm doing something terribly, terribly wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question of auth token lifetime is still very much in the air. C2DM is officially still a beta, so the Google people don't want to commit to a solid figure. Understandable, but frustrating.

That said, in my experience, if you use a dedicated Google account for C2DM purposes, the CAPTCHA challenge never comes up.

Comment: So far we haven't received the CAPTCHA challenge after initial installation (it required a IRB console session on the cluster to solve - I have since written a page for future deployments), though we have had the tokens expire between one and two weeks time.  For now I'm just going to reauthenticate via a cron job every three days.

Comment: 1-2 weeks? Craziness. Will take that into account, thank you.